# Unable to achieve 60fps animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I REALLY want to achieve 60fps animations. Specifically, on my input elements on the `focus` event. The highest (according to Chrome Developer Tools) fps I can achieve is about 18fps.

I am using everything that is said to be best practice: `window.requestAnimationFrame` in my JavaScript, `will-change` in my css, and i'm using transforms for the actual animations. Even with all of these set in place, my animations aren't near 60fps.

```js
var form = {};

function addActive(element) {
 element.highlightElement.classList.add("input-highlight-active");
}

function removeActive(element) {
 element.highlightElement.classList.remove("input-highlight-active");
}
// loops through the entire object removing "active" class on all elements except fo rthe element that is the target.
function setNewState(element, id, obj) {
 for (var key in obj) {
  if (id === key) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(() => addActive(element));
  } else {
   removeActive(obj[key]);
  }
 }
}

// Captures the event.target.id and corresponding object to be passed to setNewState function
function handleEvent(e) {
 var active = form[e.target.id];
 var activeId = e.target.id;
 setNewState(active, activeId, form);
}

// Adds focus event listener to html elements
function addEvent() {
 var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.input-wrapper > input');
  inputElements = Array.from(inputElements);
 inputElements.map(el => el.addEventListener('focus', (e) => handleEvent(e)));
 }
  
// Creates object using input id as object key
function init() {
 var temp = {};
 var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.input-wrapper > input');
 for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
  temp[inputElements[i].id] = {
   highlightElement: inputElements[i].nextElementSibling,
   active: false
  };
 }
 return temp;
}

form = init();
addEvent();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #121217;
}
.input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px auto 40px;
    text-align: left;
}
.input-label {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.012em;
    color: #eee;
}
input {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px auto 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.012em;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fafafa;
    background-color: #121217;
    border: 0px;
    transform-origin: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.input-highlight {
    will-change: transform;
    position: absolute;
    top: 99%;
    width: 101%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #006daa;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.12s linear;
}
.input-highlight-active {
    will-change: transform;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.12s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="input-label">Full name</div>
  <input type="text" id="fullName">
  <div class="input-highlight"></div>
</div>
```

At the end of the day, I am sure i'm obsessing over something most won't notice. Ultimately, I just want to understand. Even if you tell me i've done all I can.

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your question meaningless to anyone who comes across it. Always post your code right here along with your question.

Comment: *The highest (according to Chrome Developer Tools) fps I can achieve is about 18fps.* <-- So why do you think you can go beyond this then?

Comment: That is a lot of JavaScript to add the class that actually matters to performance… https://jsfiddle.net/9pgb5mc2/

Comment: Is that little bottom bar slightly thicker color slide in from the side thing on all the effect you're trying to accomplish on focus etc? If so would you rather cut that all in half and have it all on the compositor thread instead?

Comment: Anyway, I can’t reproduce this on a fairly low-end computer (it gets 60 FPS). What kind of device are you using? And have you tried just a simple width transition, no optimization attempts?

Comment: _he highest (according to Chrome Developer Tools) fps I can achieve is about 18fps. <-- So why do you think you can go beyond this then?_ <-- Well 60fps is the goal? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: _That is a lot of JavaScript to add the class that actually matters to performance_ <-- It is rather complicated because of the application it is being used on. This way avoids touching the DOM too much on the real application.

Comment: _Anyway, I can’t reproduce this on a fairly low-end computer (it gets 60 FPS). What kind of device are you using..._ <-- I am using a MacBook Pro 16gb i7. And is there a better way for CSS transitions other than using `transform`? I though using `width` will cause extra repaints/reflows

Comment: @DanielMaixner: But this isn’t that application, so what you want is a [mre]. Is the fiddle I linked to still choppy (similar ~18 FPS problem) for you? If so, it’s closer to minimal and you can cut the rest out to improve your question. If not, that’s useful information, because it means the problem was in the difference.

Comment: (Note that if you don’t @ people, they don’t get notified, with some exceptions that didn’t apply here, so I’m a bit late replying. Sorry.)

Comment: @Ry-: Apologies, I hate being that guy that doesn't understand forum etiquette, I'm not on them enough. Anyways, yes, I was still getting about 18fps on the fiddle I originally had linked (also the code from the original post). At the end of the day, I've heard about 60fps animations being the goal. What I am getting from all this is there is still a lot more to understanding animations I need to research.

Comment: @DanielMaixner: In the one I linked. https://jsfiddle.net/9pgb5mc2/. Similar bad performance?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided, you are using CSS animations, just by applying the extra class. There's no need to call `requestAnimationFrame` because it's designed to be called multiple times via the callback.

Since you took advantage of CSS animations you only need to add the class that changes the scale ONCE on focus, then you can remove it on blur:

```
.input-highlight-active {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Because the input already has a class where the `transition` value specifies it will animate all properties (that it's able to animate), you only need to specify the property change that's animated.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8vwjaLq9/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! so I removed window.requestAnimationFrame(). From what I understand from your post, using `will-change` and `transform` will offer the best performance when it has the ability?

Comment: I'm not convinced `will-change` is necessary or even recommended. But CSS animations offer the best performance for sure.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` schedules a function to be called *once*. A lot of times that function will call `requestAnimationFrame` again, but it doesn’t here, so there’s no class being added 60x per second.

Comment: @Ry- you are so right! Thank you. I corrected my answer.